# Load dicom in another android application

Tags: android, load, dicom

Is there a way to load a Dicom image using an app like "Droid Dicom Viewer". I would like to be able pass an .dcm file from my app and load it in another app to view it.

Can this be done with intents?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open DICOM files like any other registered MIME type with an intent. I wouldn't depend on "Droid Dicom Viewer" to view your files since it fails more often than it succeeds.

(assumes that sDICOMFile is a string containing the path to the file)

```
final Intent dicom_intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
dicom_intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + sDICOMFile), "Application/dicom");
startActivity(dicom_intent);
```