# Filter by mimetype or extention in native Android file picker

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mime-types, filepicker

In Android, one can use the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` Intent to **open the native file picker** and select for example an `.mp4` file. This is achived by setting the mime type to `video/mp4` using the following code:

```
public static void pickFile(Context mContext, int REQUEST_CODE) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("video/mp4");  
        ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

In my project, I want to pick a custom extension file whose mime type is not known in android's [MimeTypeMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap) like for example .qgs or .dcm files.

To solve this I see two possibilities that we, so far, failed to implement:

1. filter by extension in the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` Intent
2. register a new mime type to android so that it can be used with the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` Intent

**is either of those options doable and how?**
or are there other approaches I missed without coding my own file picker?

Comment: Have you tried to setType as Application/dicom ? Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9196456/3967525)

Comment: I  tried to setType as `Application/dicom` , `Application/dcm`  and `x-lml/x-evm`.   It's all useless.

Comment: @DSlome64 I reverted your edits since they inverted the question. I, exactly like the OP (@Levey) am trying to filter the files shown in the file picker when using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. I'm not trying to use an intent-filter based on an extension like explained by [Commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49243961/how-to-set-intent-filter-for-just-one-file-extension)

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a custom file picker and pass the mount storage points and recursively iterate on all the file types:

```
public void scanFiles(File file) {
File[] fileArray = file.listFiles(); 
for (File f : fileArray){
    if (f.isDirectory()) 
      scanFiles(f);
    if (f.isFile() && (f.getpath().endswith("..qgs") || //any extensions)) {
        //Add to your list 
       }
    }
}
```

And call scan files for all the mount points in android using a process builder and mount command and you can add checks for all the mount points you wish to support.

Answer (score 1):

> one can use the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT Intent to open the native file picker

That is not a "file picker". There is no requirement that every `DocumentsProvider` on the device be serving documents that happen to be files.

> I want to pick a custom extension file whose mime type is not known in android's MimeTypeMap like for example .qgs or .dcm files

There is no requirement that every `DocumentsProvider` on the device be using documents that have filenames for their files. The names that you see are "display names", and while for some providers they will be filenames, for other providers they can be anything that the provider wants.

> is either of those options doable

No.

> or are there other approaches I missed without coding my own file picker?

If you *only* want files, there are plenty of [existing file picker implementations available in libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35). `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is there for when you want to work with all possible document sources (removable storage, cloud providers, etc.), not just files.

Comment: I was away of connection for 2 days and just missed the bounty exipiration. How Can I award the bounty to this answer?

Comment: @mbernasocchi: At this point, I do not think you can do that. It was auto-awarded by the system. Don't worry about it. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I can tell all custom file pickers won't work on Android 11+, since the user cannot grant global access to storage. So SAF ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is the ONLY option. That makes its limited API and filtering very painful.