# How to set intent filter for just one file extension?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intentfilter

I'm searching for a solution to set intent filters for just one file extension.  I tried many examples on the web and the following is the only one that worked:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

  <data
    android:mimeType="*/*"
    android:pathPattern=".*\\.life"
    android:scheme="file" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

  <data
    android:mimeType="*/*"
    android:pathPattern=".*\\.life"
    android:scheme="content" />
</intent-filter>
```

The problem is that every file can now be opened with my app, not only the ".life" files. What is wrong in the intent filters? I also tried different MIME-Types and try to add host but then it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Which mimetype has your file extension?

Comment: Custom file extensions are pretty much doomed to failure on Android. IMHO, you will be better off allowing users to open content from inside of your app (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`).

Comment: @greenapps its originally a zip file. I tried it with "application/zip" but it didnt worked. I think a Filepicker is the best alternative in this case. Dont know how other developers handle this..